# How To Display Details item from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

anyone know how to display details item in other fragment detail when everytime im click item from listview? and how to set them? and anyone have an example for this?

and what is better to show details using dialog or fragment?

[image]
in listview only show : 
**- Nama, gambar1, tipe, mainmuscle, othermuscle, alat, rating on details** fragment i want to show : 
-Nama, gambar1, tipe, mainmuscle, othermuscle, alat, rating, **deskripsi, gambar2, gambar3, gambar4**

here my code :

Fragment.java

```
    public class AbdominalFragment extends Fragment {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = AbdominalFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http.......";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public AbdominalFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("tipe").equals("abdominal")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                        exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));
                                        exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("tipe"));
                                        exercise.setMainmuscle(obj.getString("mainmuscle"));
                                        exercise.setAlat(obj.getString("alat"));
                                        exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("othermuscle"));
                                        exercise.setRating(obj.getDouble("rating"));


                                        // adding exercise to exercise array
                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation has the example you want.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: What is the issue exactly? JSON Parsing, passing data or replacing another fragment or something else?

Comment: sorry for that, actually i want to know how to display display item when im click one from listview with details items

Comment: You need to google it first and see. Anyways for a starter this should be helpfull... http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/07/fragment-list-with-image-and-text-with.html

Comment: hmm your link its like two fragment, but how to cast when item click move into another fragment and get the detail items? like images i give on first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse the fragment are better, as they adapts to size of screen, eg if its tablet, it will show the list and details side by side, else in phone on click of list the detail screen will appear.

Follow this link for example.

http://mobileappdocs.com/android.html

Comment: Thanks, this source that i want, but how to implemet itemonclick on my code, could you help me pls?

Comment: that is also there in above example.

Comment: thanks btw already see and dont know wheres i must put the code :D